# Where should I put the image download logic on Android, according to the MVP pattern?

Tags: android, mvp, android-mvp

I'm writing an Android application and although I already have read about MVP and saw some examples in Android, I'm in doubt about how should I structure this part of the app.

NOTE: My app follows a structure very similar to: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp

In this app, the Model should fetch JSON data from a web service. This data, among other stuff, contains links of images that the app should download asynchronously. And, after downloading, these images should be presented to the user.

How should I approach this?

Right now, my idea is to add the web service request logic on the Model (I'm also using the Repository pattern) and the download logic on the Presenter. Something like this (the code is just an example):

```
class MyPresenter {
    ....

    void init() {
        myRepositoryInstance.fetchDataAndSaveLocally(new MyCallback() {

            @Override
            public void success(List<Thing> listOfThings) {
                // do some other stuff with listOfThings data
                ...

                List<URL> imagesURL = getImagesURLs(listOfThings);

                // config/use Android DownloadManager to download the images
                ...

                registerReceiver(onImageDownloadComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
            }

            @Override
            public void error() {// logging stuff, try again...}
        });
    }

    void onImageDownloadComplete() {
        URL path = getWhereTheImageWasSaved();
        Thing thing = getInstanceOfThingAssociatedWithThisImage();
        myRepositoryInstance.updatePathOfThingImage(thing, path);
        viewInstance.updateTheViewPager(); // I'll probably show these images on a ViewPager
    }

    ....
}
```

Does this makes sense? Does the download logic belongs to the Presenter? Am I putting too much logic on the Presenter?

NOTE: I' thinking about putting the download logic in the Presenter because the DownloadManager needs a Context (btw, Glide needs too). Alternatively, I know that I can use an AsyncTask on the Model to download using an HttpURLConnection, but how should I inform the download result back to the Presenter? In the latter, should I use events?

NOTE 2: I would love if I could unit test this part of the app (Mocking the DownloadManager). So, passing the Context to the Model is not an option, as it breaks the MVP (IMHO) and would be much harder to unit test it.

Any informed help would be appreciated!

### Updates

Thanks for you response @amadeu-cavalcante-filho. Let me address each issue. First, the Context problem: I need a Context, if I use Glade (an image download library) or DownloadManager, to download the images, thus, if I download the images on the Model (repository) I’ll have to give to the Model a Context instance and this clearly breaks the MVP.

Second, the MVVM, I don’t know much about the MVVM, but it seems to me that the Model in MVP should know how to fetch data (https://medium.com/@cervonefrancesco/model-view-presenter-android-guidelines-94970b430ddf) using a repository pattern or something like that.

Third, I'm prone to accept that the Presenter can indeed download the images (this is specifically the example that I constructed in my question). But, my problem is: should the Presenter know about Android stuff (the Context in this case)? This is a huge part of my question, where the Android stuff should be in the MVP? The only place that can know about Android stuff  is the view, but the download logic clearly doesn’t belong there.

Comment: Asynk task has a method onPostExecute where you can implement youre own callback in order to inform  what you want about the download result

Comment: Thanks, I know that, @GiulioPettenuzzo. If I use an Async task on the Model (repository) the problem becomes: How do I inform to the Presenter about the end of the download without breaking the MVP? Should I use events to inform the Presenter? Is it a method call to the Presenter sufficient, if so, does the Model should be aware of the Presenter?

Comment: @gpedote use callbacks to communicate back to presenter, this way model doesn't know who called it

Comment: "The only place that can know about Android stuff is the view, but the download logic clearly doesn’t belong there." You can use a util that knows about Android stuff and create a layer of abstraction to operate something the Presenter layer. Hava look at https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the update the question seems to be quite different from what I thought firstly,

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addtask_act);

        // Set up the toolbar.
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        AddEditTaskFragment addEditTaskFragment = (AddEditTaskFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.contentFrame);

        String taskId = getIntent().getStringExtra(AddEditTaskFragment.ARGUMENT_EDIT_TASK_ID);

        setToolbarTitle(taskId);

        if (addEditTaskFragment == null) {
            addEditTaskFragment = AddEditTaskFragment.newInstance();

            if (getIntent().hasExtra(AddEditTaskFragment.ARGUMENT_EDIT_TASK_ID)) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString(AddEditTaskFragment.ARGUMENT_EDIT_TASK_ID, taskId);
                addEditTaskFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            }

            ActivityUtils.addFragmentToActivity(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                    addEditTaskFragment, R.id.contentFrame);
        }

        boolean shouldLoadDataFromRepo = true;

        // Prevent the presenter from loading data from the repository if this is a config change.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Data might not have loaded when the config change happen, so we saved the state.
            shouldLoadDataFromRepo = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(SHOULD_LOAD_DATA_FROM_REPO_KEY);
        }

        // Create the presenter
        mAddEditTaskPresenter = new AddEditTaskPresenter(
                taskId,
                Injection.provideTasksRepository(getApplicationContext()),
                addEditTaskFragment,
                shouldLoadDataFromRepo);
    }
```

Here is an example from https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture

You can see that the repository (which fetch data) is passed to the presenter already injected with the application context. So, you are passing the Repository which is your abstraction to handle data to your presenter, then you have testability because you can control those two enviroments and you can have the `Context` passed to your repository where you can fetch data.

```
public AddEditTaskPresenter(@Nullable String taskId, @NonNull TasksDataSource tasksRepository,
            @NonNull AddEditTaskContract.View addTaskView, boolean shouldLoadDataFromRepo) {
        mTaskId = taskId;
        mTasksRepository = checkNotNull(tasksRepository);
        mAddTaskView = checkNotNull(addTaskView);
        mIsDataMissing = shouldLoadDataFromRepo;

        mAddTaskView.setPresenter(this);
    }
```

When you whant to test. You could do something like.

```
@Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<TasksActivity> mTasksActivityTestRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<TasksActivity>(TasksActivity.class) {

                /**
                 * To avoid a long list of tasks and the need to scroll through the list to find a
                 * task, we call {@link TasksDataSource#deleteAllTasks()} before each test.
                 */
                @Override
                protected void beforeActivityLaunched() {
                    super.beforeActivityLaunched();
                    // Doing this in @Before generates a race condition.
                    Injection.provideTasksRepository(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext())
                        .deleteAllTasks();
                }
            };
```

And, as your `Presenter` does not know that your `Repository` has a Context of the activity, you can test it passing a mock object that implements the same methods, but does not need the application context, so you can test.
Like:

```
public class AddEditTaskPresenterTest {

    @Mock
    private TasksRepository mTasksRepository;

    @Mock
    private AddEditTaskContract.View mAddEditTaskView;

    /**
     * {@link ArgumentCaptor} is a powerful Mockito API to capture argument values and use them to
     * perform further actions or assertions on them.
     */
    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<TasksDataSource.GetTaskCallback> mGetTaskCallbackCaptor;

    private AddEditTaskPresenter mAddEditTaskPresenter;

    @Before
    public void setupMocksAndView() {
        // Mockito has a very convenient way to inject mocks by using the @Mock annotation. To
        // inject the mocks in the test the initMocks method needs to be called.
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        // The presenter wont't update the view unless it's active.
        when(mAddEditTaskView.isActive()).thenReturn(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void createPresenter_setsThePresenterToView(){
        // Get a reference to the class under test
        mAddEditTaskPresenter = new AddEditTaskPresenter(
                null, mTasksRepository, mAddEditTaskView, true);

        // Then the presenter is set to the view
        verify(mAddEditTaskView).setPresenter(mAddEditTaskPresenter);
    }

    @Test
    public void saveNewTaskToRepository_showsSuccessMessageUi() {
        // Get a reference to the class under test
        mAddEditTaskPresenter = new AddEditTaskPresenter(
                null, mTasksRepository, mAddEditTaskView, true);

        // When the presenter is asked to save a task
        mAddEditTaskPresenter.saveTask("New Task Title", "Some Task Description");

        // Then a task is saved in the repository and the view updated
        verify(mTasksRepository).saveTask(any(Task.class)); // saved to the model
        verify(mAddEditTaskView).showTasksList(); // shown in the UI
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks once more for you response @AmadeuCavalcanteFilho. Your answer looks great. I am considering it and as soon as I figure out if this solves my problem, I'll mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a Presenter without the need of having a view explicitly linked to that Presenter. In other words, you can have a presenter only to encapsulate some logical. In your case, you can have a presenter that only knows how to fetch and provide some images. And your view can make use of this specific presenter.

I did not get why would you have to pass the context to the model.

> Right now, my idea is to add the web service request logic on the
>   Model (I'm also using the Repository pattern) and the download logic
>   on the Presenter. Something like this (the code is just an example):

You could do that. However, it seems more like MVVM where you put logical into Model and the Model knows how to fetch data.

In your case, you want to follow MVP, so the model only holds data (pieces of information/data). So, you can have one Presenter that knows how to download your images. And you can have some `Utils` that could help you with the request part. You can have another model for that `Presenter` that download images for saving your images, like a cache. And, again if you want to make some sort of cache logic, you should do on the same presenter that knows how to download an image. Or, if it becoming too big and complex, you can make a `Presenter` that only knows hot to cache stuff.

Once your `Presenter` only knows how to download an image, or only knows how to save an image. You can test it easy, just pass a link to your `Presenter` method and check if it could handle download the image.

Note: I did not understand how could be convenient or important you pass context for your model unless it knows some sort of cache using Android preferences?

> NOTE 2: I would love if I could unit test this part of the app
>   (Mocking the DownloadManager). So, passing the Context to the Model is
>   not an option, as it breaks the MVP (IMHO) and would be much harder to
>   unit test it.

Comment: Thanks for you response @AmadeuCavalcanteFilho, I updated my question to address those issues.

Comment: *You can have a Presenter without the need of having a view explicitly linked to that Presenter* - that makes no sense. What would it be presenting?

Comment: @TimCastelijns  You can have a service, which does stuff in the background but you do not want to put your logic on that service to be the slave of android API, however, you can put that on one presenter that has no view, but handle logic for some service and is testable.